# As a broker, get real-time data from exchanges

Tags: api, finance, trade, stock

I would like to build something like "tradingview.com" for a private broker

I've been crawling the entire internet with the quest of "Finding something that will actually fit that requirement"

I've learned a lot, trust me I knew nothing about stocks / exchanges / brokers / investment, now I have a very poor idea of everything however I just don't get to see the right path to get data as a broker as most of the APIs I've found are data for the investors not for the brokers.

Tradingview offers several brokers to buy/sell whatever investors needs however, as a broker, where do I crawl data from?

Do I have to call exchanges in order to get a license to get real-time data in order to create my financial instruments or should I just go to this [article](https://medium.com/@andy.m9627/the-ultimate-guide-to-stock-market-apis-for-2020-1de6f55adbb) and start doing PoCs of API consumption and display some simple linear/area charts with highcharts should I go to [this other website](https://www.programmableweb.com/category/financial/apis?category=19968) which seems to be a good place to find APIs but it does not look like what I need, also highcharts [stock charts](https://shop.highsoft.com/stock) seem to be a good but there's several other websites that do offer some crazy charts like the ones available at tradingview.

Basically what I need is some guidance of how to get data as a broker from exchanges in order to build private financial tools available for this broker's clients.

Do not limit the budget let it hit the fan

I could scrape the hell out tradingview using websockets but I guess there might be a better way to get that data like a membership, agreement, or whatever is required from exchanges

Comment: asking for open data solutions to build a proprietary tool sure is something. "Do not limit the budget let it hit the fan" - no open data solution requires cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar with a friend.

We built a perl (but would work in python/R/etc) just as well, and stock by stock we used the Yahoo Finance API, which seems to have been removed in its earlier form, but [through Rapid API](https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-the-yahoo-finance-api/) you can access the same information. With the data we retrieved, we created a [postgres database](https://www.postgresql.org/) with the various stock price values each day (OCHL). We took some time to build up the data, so as to not violate the (at the time) terms of service of the Yahoo API.

Also, just because data can be found on the internet, doesn't mean you can use it for your purposes. There may be copyright or fair use conditions attached to it.

Just on your idea to scrape tradingview.com, I suspect it would probably be violating the terms of service of your membership, so be careful.

Note: I have no connection social/financial connection with Rapid API.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot of sharing your experience, this is really meaningful and does offer insight regarding my doubt